# Prove that n is unique for the function σ(n)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The function σ(n) is the sum of the divisors of n, including n itself. Find the n
for which σ(n) = 15, and prove that n is unique. Help! I've been stuck on the second part (the proof) for a while now.

Comment: Since $\sigma(n)\ge n+1$, there's not too many cases to consider.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate?

Comment: For every $n$, we know that $n$ and $1$ both divide $n$.

Comment: How does this prove that $n$ is unique?

Comment: Certainly, you'd only need to check all the numbers up to 14 to prove uniqueness; anything above 14 can't have $\sigma(n)=15$.

Comment: So I should solve $σ(n)$ for all numbers from $1$ through $14$ to prove uniqueness?

Comment: It doesn't directly prove that. Instead, I'm saying you only need to consider a few cases (in this case, $14$), so if you want, you could check $\sigma(n)$ for every value of $n$ from $1$ to $14$. You don't need to check for $n\ge 15$.

Comment: And if all values of $n$ result in values for $σ(n)$ that are not $15$, then $n$ is unique?

Comment: For a number significantly larger than $15$, say around $100$, it could be helpful to use some "theory" to cut down on the computations. But for $15$ it is definitely not worthwhile, since the calculations are neither hard nor lengthy.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Crazed It takes less than 10 minutes to work out $\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \sigma(3), \ldots, \sigma(14)$.  If by "for a while now" you meant substantially more than 10 minutes, then it would be fair to say that this is an easy way to prove uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $15$ is small we begin with $n=2^m$. We see immediately that $2$ and $2^2$ are not solution but $\sigma(2^3)=1+2+4+8=15$ gives a solution.

With $2\cdot3$ and $2^2\cdot3$ one has $\sigma(2\cdot3)=1+2+3+6\lt 15$ and $\sigma(2^2\cdot3)=1+2+4+3+6+12\gt 15$ Furthermore for $3^2$ one has $\sigma(3^2)=1+3+9\lt 15$

For other integers it is clear we would have  $\sigma(n)\lt 15$ for $5,7,11,13$  and $\sigma(n)\gt 15$ elsewhere.

Thus $n=8$ is the unique solution.